latexmk doesn't rebuild when date changes using `\today`
I found a really strange issue with latexmk. I am using VSCode with the Latex Workshop extension to compile my documents and I use the latexmk (lualatex) recipe (which simply runs latexmk with the -lualatex option). Yesterday (June 17), I compiled my document and it built fine. One nice feature of latexmk is that if I run it again, it doesn't do anything because it knows all the targets are built and up to date. Because of that, when I opened the document today (June 18) and compiled it, it didn't do anything because nothing changed since yesterday so it already had the up-to-date build from yesterday. However, my document prints the date on the title page using the \today macro, which obviously changes every day, so when I compiled my document today, it still showed "June 17" on the title page despite the fact that today's date is "June 18". It's a minor bug, since any changes I make to the document, or simply deleting the old build, cause latexmk to recompile it and update the date, but it's still a bug. Is there a way to tell latexmk that if it sees the \today macro or any other time-dependent macro, then it should rebuild the document to re-evaluate those macros?

You could use a cron job or similar to delete the .aux file at midnight.

you could add a line of perl to your latexmk to delete the output pdf if it is older than today, then the rest of latexmk will kick in and rebuild it

\today is not the current date but the compilation date.

@PaulGaborit the OP didn't say \today is the current date. They did say that they are trying to compile the document again to reflect the new compilation date using \today, but latexmk didn't perform the compilation even though it can theoretically know that it needs to do so.

Latexmk's point of view is that (the relevant parts of) the output files -- pdf etc -- depend only on the contents of the input files.  So dependence on something else other than the contents of files, e.g., current date, aren't part of that approach.
